Class D Amplifier: MOSFET Gate Driver and Power MOSFET Confusion
So at the output of the comparator stage is a modulated PWM signal. I saw in some designs that the modulated PWM signal goes to one input of the MOSFET driver and the same PWM signal but inverted, goes to another input of the MOSFET driver. I was wondering why that is.
Another question is for the power MOSFET stage. Why are two MOSFETs used instead of one if I am using a single power supply? And if I am using two power MOSFETs, should I use two N-types or one N-type and one P-type? I am also really confused as to why one output signal from the driver goes to one gate of a MOSFET and another output signal from the driver goes to the gate of the second MOSFET. And when the top MOSFET is on, the bottom is off, right? And vice versa.

Post a schematic or reference of the topology you are talking about.

I posted a surface level view of it. @MOSFET

Post a reference to your schematic - you are describing an H-bridge topology, but your schematic is showing a (incomplete, unipolar) half-bridge.


I saw in some designs that the modulated PWM signal goes to one input of the MOSFET driver and the same PWM signal but inverted, goes to another input of the MOSFET driver. I was wondering why that is.

This is done whenever the output stage is using two N-channel MOSFETs. Unlike a P-channel and N-channel pair where a high gate voltage would turn the N-channel on and the P-channel off, and a low one the opposite, if the same gate signal was used to drive both N-channel MOSFETs, they would both turn on and just short the power supply through themselves. So one must invert the drive signal fed to one of the MOSFETs to ensure that when one is on, the other is off. It is similar to if you tried to make a Class AB amplifier using two NPN transistors (which is possible to do) instead of an NPN and PNP complimentary pair.

Why are two MOSFETs used instead of one if I am using a single power supply?

The power supply has nothing to do with it. Two power supplies in series are identical to one power supply, it doesn't matter. The circuit just sees a voltage difference. Likewise, there is no difference between having a 0V rail or a -12V rail. You can choose to label the -12V as 0V/ground and relabel the other voltages accordingly, and this will be just as valid.
A class D is really just a class AB amplifier that operates the two transistors as switches instead of linear amplifiers. That's what it comes down to. If you remove one MOSFET, it is no longer a class D amplifier, it is a class A amplifier. And class A amplifiers must always conduct and be operated in the linear region, so you cannot operate the single MOSFET as a switch and amplifier in this case.

if I am using two power MOSFETs, should I use two N-types or one N-type and one P-type?

As mentioned, there is no if here. Using one MOSFET is not possible. As for whether you use a complimentary pair or two N channels (or, for whatever reason, two P channels which is also possible) is really up to you. Using a P and an N allow you to connect the gates together and drive them directly from one comparator output similar to how one drives the bases of a totem pole bipolar transistor output stage in a class AB.
Using to N-channels or two P-channels requires a bit more circuitry and complexity because one of the two transistors needs to be driven by an inverted signal.
The reason this is done is that P-channel MOSFETs are, well, bad. The P-doped silicon is simply not as good of a conductor as n-doped, so P-channel mosfets will always have higher on resistance and lower efficiencies compared to their n-channel cousins. And by extension, there aren't really complimentary MOSFETs in the sense that one will have the same performance/properties/switching characteristics as another, only with opposite polarity. So the only way to get a switch with similar properties with MOSFETs is to use a pair of the same N-channel (or P-channel - but again, no reason to do that).
So you will get higher efficiency by going with two N-channels, and probably slightly lower distortion (though not enough to actually matter at least to the human ear) but at the cost of more complexity in the drive circuitry.
Choosing P and N channel will sacrifice some efficiency but will be simpler and cheaper to build.

The reason you need a half bridge is because the speaker needs to move in the forward direction and the reverse direction. If only one mosfet is used, it would only be able to move in one direction.
The mosfet gate driver that you've shown would be a half bridge mosfet driver. These are able to drive the high side and low side mosfets. Some designs will use independent gate drivers for the high and low side mosfet.
Personally I almost always use N-Channel for high side mosfets unless it's very low power. If you use a half bridge driver, a lot of times they will utilize a bootstrap diode and capacitor to drive the high side. If you start getting into higher power circuits, the choices for p-channel fets begins to drop off.
One important thing with a half bridge is to make sure that you insert deadtime when driving both mosfets. Deadtime is a period of time where both the high and low side mosfet are turned off. This is to ensure there isn't shoot through (when both mosfets are on and it shorts the voltage rail).
Here's some terms that I'd recommend you search for that should help. There will be tons of information on this that will explain it more in depth.

Half bridge for Class D amplifier
Driving high side mosfets
Half bridge gate driver with bootstrap
Deadtime for half bridge


Why not use a single transistor? Consider the following two designs, in which I represent the transistor as a switch, either open or closed:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the left, with only SW1 there is only one direction that current may flow, and that is into SW1, down to ground. That's it, just current into the driver, or no current at all.
On the right, SW3 performs the same function as SW1, providing a means of "pulling" current into the driver output, but SW2 also provides a means of "pushing" current out through the load. This bi-directional current ability is necessary for a loudspeaker to oscillate its diaphragm either side of its rest position, or for a motor to rotate in either direction.
The name given to the two-switch scenario on the right is "push-pull". Technically, we would say that it is able to both sink and source current through the load, whereas the left circuit can only sink current.
You can imagine what would happen if SW2 and SW3 were closed simultaneously. This would create a short circuit across the supply, resulting in a huge current flowing from the positive supply node down to ground via the switches, potentially destroying them or the supply. This condition is called "shoot-through" and is obviously undesirable. It is necessary to ensure that either SW2 is closed, or SW3, but never both simultaneously.
The rest of your question is about using transistors to implement switches SW2 and SW3, which is a big topic. To start with, understand the "common-source" configuration of a transistor, in which the source is connected to a supply node:

simulate this circuit
M1 is an N-channel device, and M2 is P-channel. They both have their sources connected to one of the supply nodes, either 0V or +12V. This is what happens when I sweep input \$V_{IN}\$ between 0V and +12V:

For M1 (blue) a high input potential will switch it on, pulling OUT1 low, sinking current to ground through whatever load is connected at its drain. Otherwise M1 is off, and no current flows.
M2 (orange) requires a low potential at its gate to switch it on, and in that state it sources current from +12V, and down through the load.
Think about this carefully; if a low potential is applied to M1's gate, and also to M2's gate, then M1 is off and M2 is on, a perfectly acceptable situation. A high potential at those gates will switch M1 on and M2 off, also acceptable. Therefore, when we combine high-side P-channel and low-side N-channel MOSFETs into a push-pull arrangement, their gate signals should not be inverted with respect to each other:

simulate this circuit
You wouldn't actually connect the gates together like this in practice, since during transitions of \$V_{IN}\$ there will be a short interval where both M1 and M2 are on, causing shoot-through. In practice there should be a short delay between switching one off and the other on, a delay called "dead-time", but that's beyond the scope of the question.
To understand why the signals in your diagram are inverted with respect to each other, first notice that both MOSFETs are N-channel, but the upper (high-side) one has its drain connected to a fixed potential +12V. You must study behaviour of a transistor when its drain is connected to the supply, instead of the source, an arrangement called "common-drain", or "source-follower". Here are two possible implementations of the high-side switch, one using a P-channel with common-source (right), and an N-channel with common-drain (left):

simulate this circuit
Here's the response to an input potential swept from 0V to +20V. The N-channel output \$V_{OUT1}\$ is blue, the P-channel output \$V_{OUT2}\$ is orange:

In both cases, the transistor is on when \$V_{OUT}\$ is high, being "pulled up" by the transistor. It's clear though that the N-channel transistor requires a high gate potential to turn it on, in contrast to the P-channel device, which as before requires a low input.
Notice also two other important aspects:

The N-channel source-follower output (its source terminal) is a copy of the input, but 4V lower. This 4V difference corresponds to the threshold gate-source voltage of the MOSFET \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ that you find in its datasheet.

As a consequence of (1), to fully turn on the N-channel source-follower, you must apply \$V_D+V_{GS(TH)}=+(12V) + (+4V) = +16V\$ to its gate.


Point 2 above is an inconvenience, but point 1 changes everything. Since the source-follower does not invert (as the P-channel device does), if you employ it in a push-pull configuration, its gate signal must be inverted with respect to the lower N-channel transistor's gate:

simulate this circuit
To complicate matters, the high-side gate signal is not only a digital inversion of the low-side gate signal, it must go between 0V and some value far exceeding the positive supply.
Why would anyone use an N-channel device at the high-side? Because it's hard to make P-channel MOSFETs which perform as well as their N-channel cousins. For low current applications, there's a good chance you can find a suitable P-channel device, but as load current and switching speeds increase, it gets harder to find P-channel transistors with good enough performance, and the N-channel source-follower solution (with the attendant problems) becomes the only option.
